# How to automatically do rebalancing of pods in aws eks (kubernetes ) across all nodes/workers

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Suppose we have 4 nodes eks cluster in ec2-autoscaling min with 4 nodes.
A kubernetes application stack deployed on the same with one pod- one node. Now traffic increases HPA triggered on eks level. 
Now total pods are 8 pods ,two pods - on one node. Also triggered auto-scaling. Now total nodes are  6 nodes.

Its observed all pods remain in current state. Post autscaling also.

Is there a direct and simpler way?
Some of already running pods should automatically launch on the additional nodes (detect it and reschedule itself on the recently added idle worker/nodes (i:e non-utilized - by using force eviction of pods)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why do you want to do that? to balance the nodes only?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler). This project runs as a Kubernetes Job that aims at killing pods when it thinks the cluster is unbalanced.

The [`LowNodeUtilization`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler#lownodeutilization) strategy seems to fit your case:

> This strategy finds nodes that are under utilized and evicts pods, if
>   possible, from other nodes in the hope that recreation of evicted pods
>   will be scheduled on these underutilized nodes.

---

Another option is to apply a little of chaos engineering manually, forcing a Rolling Update on your deployment, and hopefully, the scheduler will fix the balance problem when pods are recreated.

You can use the `kubectl rollout restart my-deployment`. It's way better than simply deleting the pods with `kubectl delete pod`, as the rollout will ensure availability during the "rebalancing" (although deleting the pods altogether increases your chances for a better rebalance).

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to delete all those pods by selector using below command and let the deployment recreate those pods in the cluster

kubectl delete po -l key=value

There could be other possibilities. would be glad to know from others